# Haskell data type alias naming

Tags: haskell, types, naming-conventions, algebraic-data-types, type-alias

I wrote a mathematical `Vector` module in Haskell.

So I started out with:

```
data Vector a = Vector !a !a !a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Fine—this lets me use any numerical data type I want. The problem is that I don't want to be writing `Double` and `Vector Double` everywhere for the simple reason that I shouldn't have to. So I add:

```
type Scalar = Double
type Vector = Vector Scalar
```

But of course that second line is wrong, since there are now two declarations of `Vector`. So what should I change it to? I think to myself, no, I'm going to be writing this all over my code, so I want to leave the type alias simply as `Vector`. Which means I have to change the data type name. But if I change that, then I feel like I should also change the constructor, which makes everything more confusing. But if it feels awkward making the constructor have the same name as the type alias this way.

Right now I have this:

```
type Scalar = Double
type Vector = VectorT Scalar

data VectorT a = Vector !a !a !a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I picked `T` arbitrarily (I guess it stands for "type") but I'm not so sure about this. Normally when I document functions I would say `-- Calculate the magnitude of a Vector`, but with `VectorT` I feel like I should really be using *that* type name. So I resort to just referring to them as `vectors` (not capitalized)—except then I feel like I have to apply this convention to every comment for every data type.

Has anyone been in a similar situation? Can anyone think of a more elegant solution in this case?

Comment: I've seen this on a few occasions, notably the `language-c` package uses this approach to define its syntax tree representation.  If you've never encountered the style before it can feel a bit awkward, but I expect that people get accustomed to it very quickly.

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. – Phil Karlton

Comment: Maybe `VectorOf Double` if you dislike `VectorT` </bikeshed>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution to your particular problem would be to have the data type in a different module from the type synonym. That is, have a `Math.Vector` module which contains the data declaration and some generic functions (that is, functions working for all numeric types). Then, when you actually use `Vector Double` in your code a lot, just create the type synonym using a qualified import:

```
import qualified Math.Vector as MV

type Scalar = Double
type Vector = MV.Vector Scalar
```

I think this makes sense from a code organization standpoint. Particularly, if you've defined your `Vector` type to work on all numeric types, I expect the functions in that module to also work on all numeric types. The fact that you use `Vector Double` a lot in some other part of the code should not affect the module where `Vector` is actually defined. After all, it's completely reasonable to imagine using `Vector Int` a lot in yet another part of your program.

As an aside, I'm not sure calling it `Vector` is the best idea. A vector does not necessarily have to have three dimensions, so I would call your data type something like `Vector3D`. This is actually the name used in some other APIs (like the Java 3D API), so it's probably a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any specific reason to not just do

```
data Vector = Vector !Double !Double !Double deriving (Eq, Show)
```

That seems like the simplest idea to me...

Comment: This has the advantage of being `{-# UNPACK #-}`able, too.

Comment: Then I can't make it an instance of `Functor` and `Applicative`.

Comment: And it's useful to be able to `fmap` anything on a vector—if nothing else, it makes the module implementation prettier.